# What are the arguments in function fit of keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My question is about the arguments of function fit in keras [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). When we have a model with `x` as input and `y` as output. Then, if we have a batch of samples with inputs `x` and target output `y`, we can use `model.fit(x,y)` to update the model. Assuming we have a loss function `l(x,y)`, what `model.fit(x,y)` does is that it updates the weights `w` of the model as follows

> delta =0
>
> for each sample i of batch: delta <-- delta + gradient of loss(x_i,y_i) with respect to w
>
> w <-- w + delta

Now, assume we want to change the update rule as follows:

> delta =0
>
> for each sample i of batch: delta <-- delta + q_i* gradient of loss(x_i,y_i) with respect to w
>
> w <-- w + n*delta

I want to know which of the arguments of function `fit` can be used to model the cooefficients `q_i`'s and `n`:

> fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1,
>   callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None,
>   shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0,
>   steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None)

I guess one of the `class_weight` or `sample_weight` should be related to cooefficients `q_i` but I don't know which one. Any idea? And which one of these arguments can be used to model `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var `q_i` can go in the `sample_weight`. You're using a weight "for each sample in the batch". (Actually, the `sample_weight` will multiply the loss, but constants work like `c.df/dx = d(c.f)/dx`)

The var `n` is not very straightforward, but it's intimately related with the learning rate `lr` of the optimizer when you compile:

Example:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
```

What about `class_weight`? This would apply weights based on which "output class" your sample is.

While `sample_weight` should have the same length of `x` (`sample_weight.shape[0] == x.shape[0]`), `class_weight` should be a dictionary like: `{0:w0, 1:w1, 2:w2}` for the number of labels you have.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, if we have q_i's but some of q_i's are not 1, is there any variable in function fit that we can use so that it automatically normalizes these q_i's?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm interpreting your `q_i` as constant, right? You should take care of this outside the model.

Comment: Yes, they are constants, each one is a real number.